# Open MobiledatePicker on focusing on textbox in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I would like to add an mobileDatePicker on text entry field,that is whenever text entry field got focus it should a datepicker should open in a popup.Right now i am able to do so with button click "mouseOn" event. I am looking something for textbox. Please help if anyone knows about it.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out the focusIn and openField messages.  They are sent to a field when it gets focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a dataPicker is supposed to appear whenever the user opens the field, it doesn't really make sense to keep the field unlocked. Rather, lock the field and use the mouseUp message to open the datePicker. That will give a slightly better user experience. No need to bother about focus.

Comment: mouseUp does not work with Text field. I have made an blank image button and place it over the text field and after clicking over button(which seems like we are clicking on the text field) it opens datePicker which is working fine for me.Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

I believe the command you are looking for is "on openField". This message allows you to do something (e.g. open a mobileDatePicker) when the user enters a field

Comment: But it opens pop whenever it gets focus.But i want it should open when i manualy click on the text field.